# Is it possible to set the POSIX group of a file?

Tags: java, file, posix, nio

I am aware that it's possible to set the owner of a file using [`Files.setOwner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setOwner%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipal%29):

```
Files.setOwner(Path path, UserPrincipal owner);
```

However what about the POSIX *group*? There is no `such Files.setGroup()` method in the API, and not even using the `FileOwnerAttributeView` works, as there is only `setOwner` too.

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app is working on `POSIX` systems exclusively, there's [PosixFileAttributeView.setGroup()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/PosixFileAttributeView.html#setGroup%28java.nio.file.attribute.GroupPrincipal%29).

Comment: @Rollerball : good question. According [to this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/AclFileAttributeView.html), it might, but not necessarily.