# Changing group of a unix file using java

Tags: java, nio

How can you change a group of a file using java API ?
I know I can use `Files.setOwner`(Java 7) to set the owner of a file.

How can I change the group for a file on Unix Os?

**Solution** :

```
UserPrincipalLookupService lookupservice = FileSystems.getDefault()
    .getUserPrincipalLookupService();
final UserPrincipal superuser = lookupservice
    .lookupPrincipalByName("superuser");
final GroupPrincipal servicesGroup = lookupservice
    .lookupPrincipalByGroupName("services");
FileVisitor<Path> visitor = new FileVisitor<Path>() {

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir,
            IOException exc) throws IOException {
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path file,
            BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        setOwnerAndGroupForFile(superuser, servicesGroup, file);
        File[] listFiles = file.toFile().listFiles();
        for (File file1 : listFiles) {
            Files.walkFileTree(file1.toPath(), this);
        }
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
            BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        setOwnerAndGroupForFile(superuser, servicesGroup, file);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file,
            IOException exc) throws IOException {
        outputError("Problems while accesing file " + file);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    private void setOwnerAndGroupForFile(final UserPrincipal superuser,
            final GroupPrincipal servicesGroup, Path file)
            throws IOException {
        Files.setOwner(file, superuser);
        PosixFileAttributeView fileAttributeView = Files
            .getFileAttributeView(file, PosixFileAttributeView.class);
        fileAttributeView.setGroup(servicesGroup);
    }
};
Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(dataDirectoryFile.toURI()), visitor);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241967/change-file-owner-group-under-linux-with-java-nio-files

Comment: Why : `File[] listFiles = file.toFile().listFiles(); for (File file1 : listFiles) { Files.walkFileTree(file1.toPath(), this); }` ???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to set the "group" of a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686099/is-it-possible-to-set-the-group-of-a-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [`PosixFileAttributeView.setGroup()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/PosixFileAttributeView.html#setGroup%28java.nio.file.attribute.GroupPrincipal%29) with POSIX systems.

Comment: Brilliant..! Works Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @MandarKulkarni You're welcome. Consider accepting one of the answers if they covered everything in your question.

Comment: Technically, I did not get any exception and debug messages do indicate that the code is traversing though every directory/sub-directory and changing group for the file. But, when I do "ls -l" on the unix box, I can not see modified group/owner for those files ? Any ideas ?

Comment: @MandarKulkarni I don't have something to test it on right now. Consider the difference between `master` and `superuser` in your context. Is it actually supposed to change the group or is that the group it was in before?

Comment: It is expected to change the group & owner. By default all files have root as owner & group.

Comment: Ok, it was my mistake. But looks like the code is not recursively traversing through sub-directory.

Comment: @MandarKulkarni It won't recur through sub-directories. When you think about it, neither does `chown` or any of those commands. You can pretty easily write your own `FileVisitor` to check all directories and files.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out `JCraft's JSch library (Java Secure Channel)`. It does SSH for java, allowing you to authenticate as a user, then issue `chmod` or `chown` requests to your hearts content!

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a Set of `PosixFilePermission` instances to mimic chmod command:

```
  //using PosixFilePermission to set file permissions 777
    Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = new HashSet<PosixFilePermission>();
    //add owners permission
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_EXECUTE);
    //add group permissions
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_READ);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_WRITE);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_EXECUTE);
    //add others permissions
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_READ);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_WRITE);
    perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_EXECUTE);

    Files.setPosixFilePermissions(Paths.get("path/to/file"), perms);
```